# UUID or BIGSERIAL Foreign Keys Postgres

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, uuid

I have 8 tables which use UUID Primary Keys and 7 of them have UUID Foreign Keys. Would it be better for performance to use BIGSERIAL instead of UUID?

Comment: BIGSERIAL == 8 bytes, UUID == 16 bytes. Of course the shorter datatype's performance is to be better...

Comment: @Akina But is the difference big enough in real applications so it's worth changing to integer primary keys?

Comment: Depends on the operation. For example, in interactive processing it doesn't matter what type to use...

Comment: @Akina I'm mostly doing INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and SELECT operations

Comment: For small inserts the difference hardly noticeable in my experience. For bulk inserts (millions of rows in a single transaction), there is a measurable difference. For SELECT statement using  `=` I could never measure any difference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`uuid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) if you *need* it.
Don't use it if you don't.

[`bigint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) is smaller and a bit faster in multiple ways. 8 vs. 16 bytes do not sound like much, but the difference stacks up for big tables and multiple instances, and multiple indexes for each. (And rarely would either a `uuid` or `bigint` key make sense for small tables to begin with.)

`bigint` is typically also much easier on the human eye and for human handling and for representation when numbers don't get that big after all. UUID always requires 32-character representation (optionally plus dashes).

If you have two of those (PK & FK) in the same table, rows grow by 16 bytes. That may make a difference for narrow rows, or be negligible for wide rows. **More importantly**, associated indexes also grow in size. While the PK index for a `bigint` occupies 16 bytes per row (incl. 8 byte index tuple overhead), it's 24 bytes for `uuid`. If RAM is not available in abundance, that can mean the difference of several indexes residing in RAM vs. being evicted and read back from storage repeatedly. And that would be a substantial difference.

Do you even need `bigint`? Often, a 4-byte `integer` is good enough (if it's *really* good enough) ...

Related:

- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115271/what-is-the-optimal-data-type-for-an-md5-field/115316#115316)
- [PostgreSQL using UUID vs Text as primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33838373/939860)