# Postgres optimizing IN queries

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-11

I am trying to optimize the 'IN' QUERY in Postgres 11.

I tested 3 approaches:

Case 1:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE 
id1='fffe9411-3b9d-40dc-9cc6-14407785be8b' 
and 
id2 IN ('00000140-1ae9-41f7-9614-453c063cee52'...'0000693d-0570-41e2-81e9-288261b3b2e5');
```

Case 2:

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
USING  
unnest ('{00000140-1ae9-41f7-9614-453c063cee52..0000693d-0570-41e2-81e9-288261b3b2e5}'::text[]) unnestid 
WHERE 
id2 = unnestid 
and 
mytable.id1='fffe9411-3b9d-40dc-9cc6-14407785be8b';
```

Case 3:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE 
id1='fffe9411-3b9d-40dc-9cc6-14407785be8b' 
and id2 
IN (VALUES ('00000140-1ae9-41f7-9614-453c063cee52')..('0000693d-0570-41e2-81e9-288261b3b2e5'));
```

Query Plan for case 1:

```
 Delete on mytable  (cost=0.56..7.18 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.601..0.602 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using mytable_pkey on mytable  (cost=0.56..7.18 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.073..0.453 rows=6 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id1 = 'fffe9411-3b9d-40dc-9cc6-14407785be8b'::text)
         Filter: (id2 = ANY ('{00000140-1ae9-41f7-9614-453c063cee52,00005327-2400-40cc-bd22-39cc7fc6744e,00005a71-3cad-4253-9afe-dc3fe5609dc1,000062be-95ae-4485-800d-d969a232ebf1,0000663e-7675-4b93-86a5-742de1bab70d,0000693d-0570-41e2-81e9-288261b3b2e5}'::text[]))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 95
```

Query Plan for case 2:

```
Delete on mytable  (cost=7.21..8.47 rows=1 width=62) (actual time=0.691..0.693 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=7.21..8.47 rows=1 width=62) (actual time=0.650..0.656 rows=6 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (unnestid.unnestid = mytable.id2)
         ->  Function Scan on unnest unnestid  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=100 width=88) (actual time=0.019..0.022 rows=6 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=7.15..7.15 rows=5 width=43) (actual time=0.594..0.595 rows=101 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 16kB
               ->  Index Scan using mytable_pkey on mytable  (cost=0.56..7.15 rows=5 width=43) (actual time=0.087..0.554 rows=101 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (id1 = 'fffe9411-3b9d-40dc-9cc6-14407785be8b'::text)
```

Query Plan for case 3:

```
Delete on mytable  (cost=0.71..7.31 rows=1 width=62) (actual time=0.649..0.651 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=0.71..7.31 rows=1 width=62) (actual time=0.140..0.598 rows=6 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (followers.accountid = "*VALUES*".column1)
         ->  Index Scan using mytable_pkey on mytable  (cost=0.56..7.15 rows=5 width=43) (actual time=0.094..0.529 rows=101 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (id1 = 'fffe9411-3b9d-40dc-9cc6-14407785be8b'::text)
         ->  Hash  (cost=0.08..0.08 rows=6 width=88) (actual time=0.019..0.020 rows=6 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
               ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.08 rows=6 width=88) (actual time=0.010..0.013 rows=6 loops=1)
```

I am not sure which approach is more effient? 
Constraints:
1> My IN LIST can have Max 100 elements. 
2> mytable has index on id1 and id2

I am gravitating to approach 1 & 3 
[In case 3: we are making hash against IN List which is Max 100]

Reference:  [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in/91539#91539)

As Per above link case 2 and case 3 is better but what confuses me is FILTER not less expensive than doing hash join?

Hash Join, Will do sequential Scan on both inner and outer loop..

But option 1 is only doing a seq scan on mytable + filter on the IN clause.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @mustaccio: I dont know which Query out of case 1/case 2/case 3 is most efficient...where my IN Query can have Max 100 elements..

Comment: @mustaccio: I reworded my question.. to make it more clear..

Comment: Don't your statement timings and execution plans tell you which of them is more efficient?

Comment: timings are v close @mustaccio .. so no clear winner
I am not sure which execution plan is better

Comment: If the timings are the same then it sounds like there's no discernable concern between which method you use. Unless you're experiencing a specific performance issue there's probably no need to spend any time further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two revealing bits in the first query plan:

> ```
> Index Scan using mytable_pkey on mytable  (cost=0.56..7.18 rows=1 width=6)
>                                           (actual time=0.073..0.453 rows=6 loops=1)
> ```

**`rows=6`**. So it hardly matters how you apply the second filter. The first filter already did almost all the work! You are done here.
If the filter on the first UUID wasn't so selective, a multicolumn index on `(id1, id2)` might be useful.

> ```
> Index Cond: (id1 = 'fffe9411-3b9d-40dc-9cc6-14407785be8b'::text)
> ```

You are storing UUID numbers as **`text`**, which is a big waste. Use the proper type [**`uuid`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) to make storage a lot smaller and everything a lot faster. (And enforce valid UUIDs.) See:

- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115271/what-is-the-optimal-data-type-for-an-md5-field/115316#115316)
- [UUID or BIGSERIAL Foreign Keys Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256749/uuid-or-bigserial-foreign-keys-postgres/256817#256817)

[My old answer you refer to](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91539/3684) still isn't *wrong*. But it was written 2015 for Postgres 9.4. We have Postgres 14 now, which has gotten a lot smarter.

Comment: Thank you @Erwin you are correct... When I re-tested by firing 1000 queries and taking average I found that case 3 which is using 
```IN (VALUES ('00000140-1ae9-41f7-9614-453c063cee52')..('0000693d-0570-41e2-81e9-288261b3b2e5'));```

was better.. thanks for the Tip on uuid!!
We Will plan the Migration..
We have an index on (id1, id2) but it wasnt using it its interesting..
Also a Big shout out and thanks for ur posts Erwin..they were a Great source of guidance.

Comment: Like I said, while the filter `id1 = ...` is so selective, an index on `(id1, id2)` is no improvement. I.e., while there are only very rows per `id1`.

Comment: @Cppcrusaders: So is this question answered properly?

Comment: All good, your posts i General in dba.stackexchange have been a Life Saver and v reliable thank you!

Comment: If this answers your question properly, consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169168).

Comment: done thanks @Erwin